# How to get features of all the layers in QGis vector layer

Tags: python, geometry, qgis

I have a set of shape file.
And I loaded all the layers in QGis. I want to select the geometry of features of all the layers and compare them to a particular feature's geometry.
I tried the following code

```
layers = self.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
iter = layer.getFeatures()
for feature in iter:
     geom_is = feature.geometry()
     iter_1 = layers.getFeatures()
     for feat in iter_1:
         geom_all = feat.geometry()
         if geom_is == geom_all:
             check_passed = True
         else:
             check_passed = False
return check_passed
```

The program returns the following error:
     'dict' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

Comment: ...and then what happened?

Comment: @asongtoruin Program returns the following error : 'dict' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't see "layer" defined in your code. I presume it's defined earlier, right ?
2. In line 5 your code says:
   `layer**s**.getFeatures()`
   thus error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'
   layers is a dict type object. It contains all the layers (not features!!!) of your project.

to solve your problem, I think you'll need to get the layers as QgsFeatures not dict.
My proposal would be to change the first line to:

```
layers = self.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
```

then to gather all the features geometries you'll need the iter through all the layers, like so:

```
allFeatures = []
for l in layers:
  for f in l.getFeatures():
    allFeatures.append(f.geometry())
```

the only thing left is to take care about the self-check.
let me know if this helped,
cheers!